# How to handle outdated packages that are required by a dependency in package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, dependency-management, npm-vulnerabilities

Let’s say I have a dependency `some_dep` that has a vulnerability. I’m told on GitHub *“Upgrade some_dep to version 2.2.3 or later.”*

However, things get complicated when I see `some_dep` is a required dependency of a required dependency etc.

run `npm ls some_dep` to see:

```
└─┬ really_popular@5.0.0
  └─┬ someotherlibrary@0.26.0
    └─┬ something_else@12.8.17
      └─┬ snazzypackage@1.2.7
        └── some_dep@1.4.3
```

And the required version @1.4.3 is out of date with a vulnerability.

If I run `npm install some_dep@2.2.3`, this makes dependancies in my `package.json` update to include `"some_dep": "^2.2.3"`. There was no `some_dep` before in my `package.json` since it was a dependency of `really_popular` package. It was only in `package-lock.json`. So do I want `some_dep` in my `package.json` when it isn't a direct dependency of my project? It doesn’t seem right to have it there.    Also my `package-lock.json` will still have the old `some_dep` version in `package-lock.json` for the `snazzypackage` required dependency.    So it seems I'll have both versions of `some_dep` now and the issue will still be there.

What’s the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up updating the parent dependency, which I gave a pseudonym here of `really_popular`. I was putting it off because it was a big version change, and required other packages to be changed to a new version too, and it required a lot of updates to my code. But I felt, and got guidance, that updating to the new version was important if there are vulnerabilities.

But if this isn't an option, another suggestion I go was to go to the package of the parent dep, like `node_modules/snazzypackage/package.json` and change the version of `some_dep` there. I didn't try this.